# How do I model different types of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, active-relation

My app will be a database of `players`. That's the core data point of the database. Players (aka...the profiles of players) are what users will login to view/edit/update/delete.

Think of it like a recruiting database, where I (as a recruiter) can login to see the types of players I want to recruit to my team.

So what I am struggling with is how to model the User relationships. Here are the business rules.

- Each player should be able to login to update their own profile.
- Each player does NOT have to have a User account, but they CAN if they want.
- Each player has attributes that a normal 'User' record doesn't have (e.g. an avatar, academic results, a video, etc.).
- Each coach can login to view all the profiles of the players.
- Each coach should be able to add other coaches/recruiters to their account.
- Each admin should be able to CRUD players

This is where it is tricky...a `player` should just be another Model...because they are the central record for the entire app (like an image may be on an image-sharing site). Where it gets tricky is that each player `can be` associated with a user record, but doesn't HAVE to be.

What would the associations look like? What would be just a role of the `User` class and what would be an association with another model?

Comment: `User has_one :profile`?

Comment: I was thinking that...but....remember that a `user` can be a `coach` or `admin`. In that case, they won't need a `profile`.

Comment: I think you're confusing db design problem with app design/usability/whatever problem. Obviously some players will be created before respective users ever join the site so there has to be a way to "claim" the profile. Here you'll have to step up to make sure a person who claims the profile (so real world person wanting to connect to their preexisting profile) is who they say they are. This is again not a db design problem.